# How to make inbox that shows chat history to both who sent and received message

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a chat system . But i am not able to display that which user is connected to which one.

```
'SELECT *
 FROM accounts
 INNER JOIN messages
 ON accounts.id = messages.from_user WHERE to_user = ? AND from_user != ? GROUP 
 BY from_user';

 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'ss',$user,$user); // $user is a session user
```

this above query only shows the connection to the user who received the messages not the user who sent the message. For example sam sent message to freddy, so my query shows freddy that he received the message but doesn't shows sam that he sent the message

**This is my table**

```
id | from_user   |  to_user  | msg
------------------------------------
 1 |    1        |     3     | hi
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your table structure. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query. Also, you might want to start your query from the `messages` table and do two `JOIN`s on the `accounts` table (one for the sender, one for the receiver).

Comment: is my question is not clear or understandable?

Answer (score 1):

You must join the table `accounts` twice to get the details of the user who sent the message and the user who sent:

```
SELECT *
 FROM messages m
 INNER JOIN accounts a1 ON a1.id = m.from_user 
 INNER JOIN accounts a2 ON a2.id = m.to_user
```

This will give you the details for all the messages inside the `messages` table. 
Then you can apply any conditions with `WHERE` or group with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: i have used this `SELECT *
 FROM messages m
 INNER JOIN accounts a1 ON a1.id = m.from_user 
 INNER JOIN accounts a2 ON a2.id = m.to_user  WHERE to_user != ? AND from_user = ? GROUP BY from_user` but it showing same behaviour

Comment: Why `GROUP BY from_user`? You use group by when you want aggregated results.

Comment: ok i have removed `GROUP BY from_user` but it's still not working

Comment: If you use my code, do you see all the rows from the messages table?

Comment: Then apply any condition you want by adding a WHERE statement

Comment: No i have not understood

Comment: If you want all the messages from `from_user = 100` then add to my code `WHERE m.from_user = 100`

Comment: There are multiple user who can send message to each other

Comment: I know that. What I don't know is how you want the results of my code filtered. What is your expected result? Post in your question sample data and your expected result. Otherwise how can I help you?

Comment: For now just please ignore my query i have shown my database table and with an example of freddy and sam i have shown that what problem i am facing. Can you help me with your query?

Comment: Ok, suppose freddy's id is 100 and sam's id is 200. If you want to see all the messages that they exchanged you must add: `WHERE (m.from_user = 100 AND m.to_user = 200) OR (m.from_user = 200 AND m.to_user = 100)`. Is this what you want?

Comment: Anyways thank you for your time finally somehow i found a solution .